# Is elemental based evolution possible

Tags: biology, evolution, science-fiction

I am dealing with Giants and Titans in my world, and I would like to know if there are any natural ways for a creature to naturally grow elemental bodies, like resistance to fire, or ice naturally attached to their bodies/icy breath.

The closest thing I can think of is a water bear being able to dehydrate completely and survive.

Comment: There are several animals which produce substances that produce pain similar to burns. I think you should be very clear here: what exactly do you want? A creature that breathes fire or something that burns? A  arm e.g. made of ice or a body that is adapted to a cold climate? Right now your question could mean anything

Comment: I could really go with either. Being capable of holding flames/ice on the skin would be pretty nice, but also a beast capable of throwing flames, flash freezing or even producing electricity would be nice. I realize the question is broad, but id love to know what types of creatures can produce elements or even be completely unaffected by them as both relate to my giants.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with asking multiple focused questions in multiple threads instead of one big unclear broad one. E.g. how to attach ice to a creature, how to make it breathe fire, how to make it poisonous, how to make it resist temperatures in a certain range. You will also find many of these questions have already answers in this forum

Comment: True enough I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, relying on chemistry your creatures can play some ice/fire tricks.

**ICE**

Some chemical reactions need energy to occur, which results in cooling down the surrounding. If the body is able to produce these chemicals and keep them separate until needed, you could for example have a "frozen spit": a gush of saliva containing the chemicals is launched on the target, and once the chemical reaction freezes it, the target is trapped in a crust of ice. Maybe usefule for hunting small animals.

**FIRE**

Some reactions produce a lot of energy. Again, if your creatures can isolate such chemicals and use them when needed, they could play "fire" tricks.

As real life example you can refer to the "[bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle)", which produces water peroxyde and Hydroquinone as defense mechanism

> This reaction is very exothermic, and the released energy raises the temperature of the mixture to near 100 °C, vaporizing about a fifth of it.

Comment: Small sodium particles in water. Find the error. I'd maybe consider e.g. white phosphorus as it doesn't burn in water but with contact to air.

Comment: @Raditz_35, taken that out. The real life example is better.

Comment: Damn that might be nice. Making the giants bodies produce chemicals which could flash freeze, or perhaps two chemicals that mix and become immediately volatile as they exhale it. It would certainly make the giants more unique then just "they worship god X and therefore are of element X"